# Angular 2: Generate random int throws error

Tags: angular, random

I have a list where I am using a random number to choose an avatar and its throwing the following error:

```
HelloIonicPage.html:33 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

View:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index;>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img [src]="getRandomInt(0, 9)">
      </ion-avatar>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

.ts

```
getRandomInt(min, max) {
    let num =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/" + num + ".jpg"
}
```

Comment: I suppose, it sill open issue, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15464 and here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14748, So try different approach until angular guys fix it

Comment: I'm new to Angular and don't really know a better approach.  Could you give me one?

Comment: What is this code doing `let r = getRa`?

Comment: sorry, that was extraneous code

Comment: It might be mad about a dynamic `src` in the middle of iterating through a changeable list. I think this code is probably trying to change the `src` every time it evaluates `clients` (which can happen just by clicking around the page).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try trick with `background-image` and `[ngStyle]`

HTML

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index; let r = getRa" >
    <ion-avatar item-left>
     <div class="avatar-photo" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + getRandomInt(0, 9) + ')' }"></div>
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You also need additional CSS, so it custom, change as you need

```
.avatar-photo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I hope it help!

Comment: This still throws the same error.  Would I have to create `Client` component and have a variable that is the random number?  That seems like a lot of work to allow this

Comment: Hm, are you sure? I made an example http://plnkr.co/edit/9WccSBylDBmwA2jJIvXm?p=preview. What version of angular do you use?

Comment: Angular 2 or do you mean more specifically?  Could it be the fact that I'm using mine in a loop?

Comment: Yes, more specific. Also it works with `*ngFor`. Check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/wze0uutqdOntPTPDcl3b?p=preview

Comment: `Ionic Framework: 3.0.1
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.0
Angular Core: 4.0.0
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.0.0
Node: 4.2.2`

Comment: `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'url(https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/8.jpg)'. Current value: 'url(https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/7.jpg)'.`